# Send Table Data via Ajax and Web Api

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I have tables with different column and row count as JSON on client side, e.g.:

```
[
  ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  ["2008", "-5", "11", "12", "13"],
  ["2009", "20", "-11", "14", "13"],
  ["2010", "30", "15", "-12", "readOnly"]
]
```

I want to send this table to server via ajax and ASP.NET Web Api. What is the best way to do this?

I always get null as value when i want to post as text and receive it as `[FromBody]string value`. I can't use a class because of different table sizes?

Comment: how come your table size affect your classes here?

Comment: how can a table be implemented in a class?

Comment: Do you want to send the same data? I mean, can't you change it to fit your class structure?

Comment: no? i simply want to send tables of data via json. this can't be so difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer was in the ajax code. I didn't had the right data parameter. Right is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../webapi/Products',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "text", 
    data: "="+JSON.stringify( data ),
    success: function (test) {
            alert(test);
        },
        error: function (test) {
            alert("Error");
        }
```

then i can use e.g. JArray from JSON.NET to parse the value string.